# How does reference semantics work in a collection of protocol types when they are structs?

Tags: json, protocols, swift-protocols

I've stumbled upon a memory leak during decoding a JSON object, but I believe it's not related to JSONDecoder specifically. Below is an example demonstrating the issue:

```
struct AccountResponse: Codable {
    var accounts: [Account]?
}

struct Account: Codable {
    var id: String?
    var openedDate: Date?
}

protocol AccountProtocol {
    var id: String? { get }
    var openedDate: Date? { get }
}

extension Account: AccountProtocol {}

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        test()
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
    
    var userAccounts: [AccountProtocol]?
    
    func test() {
        let data =
        """
        {
          "accounts": [{
            "id": "2028658397",
            "openedDate": "2020-05-06T00:00:00Z"
          }]
        }
        """.data(using: .utf8)!
        
        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        decoder.dateDecodingStrategy = .iso8601
        self.userAccounts = (try! decoder.decode(AccountResponse.self, from: data)).accounts
    }
}
```

When I'm profiling the app with Instruments->Leaks I consistently get a memory leak:
[memory leak](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lsHaC.png)

But the thing is... if I do any of the following steps, the leak disappears:

- use concrete type `Account` instead of protocol in the userAccounts array
- make `struct Account` a **class**
- change the declaration of accounts in `AccountResponse` to **let** instead of var
- modify the `Date`-typed property to be a `String` (this one is particularly weird to me).

What's the ARC logic behind these "fixes" in relation to the mechanics of collections of protocol types?

Comment: It was probably an iOS 16 bug — the same code on iOS 17 won't reproduce the leak.